# Customize cell layouts programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I followed a tutorial on how to make a UICollectionView and my cells looked like this:
[image]

My question is how can I customize them as I want? By code, since I want to do everything with code, I would appreciate any help, links, or anything to understand everything about how to customize items and cells.

Comment: Search for "auto layout" and "programmatic constraints".

Comment: If you want help with code that you've written, you need to ***show us*** the code you've written.